# iPhone 5c Digitizer or logic board damage

Tags: screen, damage, iphone, logicboard, digitizer

My wife dropped her phone on Sunday... I don't want to replace the screen if it's the logic board and nothing can be done to recover her data. A beautiful picture:

[image: Plaid Phone]

If this were the 1970's her phone would be *so* vogue... Who didn't love plaid back then?

Anyway... I have taken the screen off and checked the connections, put everything back together. No change.

- The phone still rings when called
- The phone vibrates when switched into silent mode
- The digitizer is not working - the phone cannot be "unlocked" and calls cannot be answered
- There was a screw that had detached from the retaining plate where the screen connects to the logic board

  - [image: Loose Screw]
- I tried hard reboots (power + home)

  - The home and power buttons are still recognized but this has no impact on the artifacting display
  - During the hard reboot the display goes blank and then lights up again after being restarted.
- I tried disconnecting / reconnecting the battery from the logic board

  - This had no impact on the display. We've gone plaid.

Curious if anyone can tell whether this symptom is indicative of a bad logic board or if the display / digitizer cables have been damaged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your phone rings when called, that tells you a couple things that the phone is able to do:

- The phone is able to turn on.
- The phone is able to process the received call (and I'm guessing all of iOS's pretty effects with loading it as well).
- The phone is able to process events from all of the phone's physical buttons (the Lock button, Volume Up/Down, and the Home button).

However, as it seems, the phone **isn't** able to send touch events to the UI, meaning the digitizer is broken.

Screw in the loose screw, replace the screen/digitizer unit, and reboot. All will be well. :)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your take on it! I have ordered the part and will respond with my findings :)

Comment: Replaced it today and it was the screen :) Thanks for the advice, much appreciated!

Comment: @Shrout1 That's good to hear!

Comment: Happy wife, happy life :)

Comment: Aaaand this morning she dropped it and shattered the new screen. :P

Comment: @Shrout1 ouch! Do you have to repair it again?

Comment: Lol yes I ordered the new screen and an otterbox for it this morning. Pesky gravity :P